# Blade template: Is it possible to yield a section which is defined in parent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yield, sections

I'm trying to insert a piece of code wherever it is yielded, even if it is yielded inside a child view. I want the child view to load the section which is defined inside the parent. This should be a different position for every child.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use @include() to include the child section wherever you want.

Comment: Like a partial?